# How to search specific string in another col

Tags: python, pandas

What I want to do is, I have several columns and I wanna search each colum string in a column here is the example.

Here is my df.head()

```
Check  index                                            reviews                                            summary                                            output1                                           output2  ... output35 output36 output37 output38 output39 output40
0  True      1  After realizing my old mascara had a petroleum...  Output: Quality: love the wand (positive); Len...                  Quality: love the wand (positive)  Lengthening: lengthens my lashes well (positive)  ...     None     None     None     None     None     None
1  True      2  Best mascara I’ve ever used. Makes my non-exis...  Output: Makes lashes visible (positive); Non-e...                    Makes lashes visible (positive)              Non-existent Asian lashes (negative)  ...     None     None     None     None     None     None
2  True      3  I've never had a mascara that made my lashes l...               Output: Look: long lashes (positive)                       Look: long lashes (positive)                                              None  ...     None     None     None     None     None     None
3  True      4  It is clump and smudge-free with an awesome la...  Output: Clump-free (positive); Smudge-proof (p...                              Clump-free (positive)                           Smudge-proof (positive)  ...     None     None     None     None     None     None
4  True      5  And I’m going to buy it again, and again, and ...  Output: Quality: impressed by a mascara before...  Quality: impressed by a mascara before (positive)            Extends Lashes: huge impact (positive)  ...     None     None     None     None     None     None
```

What I want to do is to check if the values ​​of all output columns (except columns with N/A in them) are inside the string in the reviews column.

here is a example for reviews column and the output1 column value.

Reviews = "After realizing my old mascara had a petroleum by-product in it, I needed a new one I felt good about putting on my beautiful lashes. I needed one that had a clean formula, produced by a company making more environmentally sustainable efforts. I was so excited to receive this mascara after ordering it, and it did not disappoint. I love natural, clean beauty products. I love the wand on this mascara, and it lengthens my lashes very well. I like using mascara because I love my lashes, and I don't want to use falsies or extensions. This mascara takes me from girlboss to goddess in less than 2 minutes. It's so easy to use, non-messy, and dries fast. Even if you do or don't feel like doing a full-face of makeup, this mascara will upgrade your look. It is a must-have and worth every cent."

Output1 = "Quality: love the wand (positive)"

I wanna search "love the wand" value is in reviews column

```
## Read your DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel("ilia.xlsx")
df.insert(0, "Check","True")
# Split the values in the 'summary' column and create new columns

split_values = df['summary'].str.split(";", expand=True)
for i in range(split_values.shape[1]):
    df[f'output{i+1}'] = split_values[i]

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lstrip() if x.dtype == "object" else x)
df["output1"] = df["output1"].str.replace("Output: ", "")
df["Check"] = df.apply(lambda x: any(i in x['reviews'] for i in x['summary'].split(";")), axis=1)

print(df.head())




df.to_excel("foo.xlsx", index=False)
```

Comment: Help us to help you - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue easily. Take a minute to check - How to create [mcve] Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is what you are looking for:

```
df['reviews'].str.contains('love the wand').any()
```

From [Statology](https://statology.org/pandas-check-if-column-contains-string/)

Comment: I tried it too but, the output columns value has not a standart.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your question. If you are looking in the summary column you can use 'summary' rather than reviews. You can implement Boolean logic if you want it in both.

Comment: The summary column is the aggregate of the output columns. Therefore, I cannot search with the summary column. Because while some parts pass inside the reviews text, some do not, and I'm trying to distinguish them.

Comment: So you want to only search between Output: and the ; after for this 'love the wand' within the review column. Am I understanding correctly?